# mkdir(): Permission denied

Tags: php, apache, yii, permissions

I have 777 on all files on my server. PHP 5.4 (no safe_mode)

Site works on other servers. It's Yii framework

```
 mkdir(): Permission denied

/var/www/html/project/framework/web/CAssetManager.php(225)

213             return $this->_published[$path];
214         elseif(($src=realpath($path))!==false)
215         {
216             $dir=$this->generatePath($src,$hashByName);
217             $dstDir=$this->getBasePath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$dir;
218             if(is_file($src))
219             {
220                 $fileName=basename($src);
221                 $dstFile=$dstDir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$fileName;
222 
223                 if(!is_dir($dstDir))
224                 {
225                     mkdir($dstDir,$this->newDirMode,true);
226                     chmod($dstDir,$this->newDirMode);
227                 }
```

Here `ls -l` after chown, not help

```
drwsrwsrwx.  2 apache apache    4096 июля   3 16:44 assets
drwxrwxrwx.  5 apache apache    4096 июня  10 14:52 bootstrap
drwxrwxrwx. 19 apache apache    4096 июля   3 16:04 framework
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache     326 июля   3 16:42 index.php
drwxrwxrwx. 10 apache apache    4096 июля   3 16:04 protected
drwxrwxrwx.  3 apache apache    4096 июня  20 13:28 soap
drwxrwxrwx.  3 apache apache    4096 июля   3 16:04 themes
```

Comment: You need 777 on the dir you're trying to make a dir in as well, or change it's owner.

Comment: You should also use octal representation for file and directory permissions. `0777` instead of `777`.

Comment: It's Yii framework. I can't change this code.. All /www/ have 777

Comment: I have seen this fail before even with 777 if the directory owner is not the webserver user that is running the script. change the directories so they are owned by the web server user (apache, nobody or www-data etc depending on your server) and this will normally solve your problem. Another cause is the drive being full

Comment: Can you show us the results of `ls -la` in the parent directory (and that directory's parent)?

Comment: add some info... This not help...

Comment: @user2546911: do `ls -la` on your parent directory and post the output here, as @ChrisHanson told you.

Comment: If @cb0 answer doesn't get there, provide the result of var_dump($dstDir).

Comment: All parents have apache owner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check SELinux and turn off it.. Now it works!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that:

- the web directory is owned by the apache user. ("ls -al" will tell you)
- the parent directory in which you want to create is also owned by this user.
- the parent directory isn't a mount in which you don't have write permissions
- the path you want to create is correct (var_dump($dstDir) will tell you)
- $this->newDirMode is contains a correct permission value. (If you are running on windows this will be ignored)

If there is no problem and it still doesn't work I would do:

- make yourself the apache user and try to create it manually ("sudo -u apache" if your username is apache)
- try to omit the third parameter 'true' in  "mkdir($dstDir,$this->newDirMode,true);" and create all directories one after another
- inspect the logs ("/var/log/apache" is your friend)

Hope this helps.

Comment: What user is defined in your /etc/apache2/apache2.conf ? (Search for 'User' followed by 'Group')

Comment: I think, SELinux.. Other domain is work in /var/www/html/, but i haven't any info in SELinux

Comment: Your 'ls -la' shows me that this should be ok :(
Does creating the directory manually worked ?

Answer (score 3):

SELinux may be the problem.  Try turning it off manually:

```
setenforce 0
```

Answer (score 1):

SELinux was the culprit for my set up. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Permissions and ownership was also an issue. My solution: chown -R apache basic/

Comment: chgrp -R apache basic/

Comment: chmod 755 permissions for your webroot recursively as well got mine working followed by the 'setenforce 0' and the always helpful 'service httpd restart' just in case =) thank you everyone for your help on this one. Looking forward to playing with Yii 2.0