# mkdir: cannot create directory `pgsql': Permission denied

Tags: linux, command-line

I want to create directory like below:

```
ajs@ajs-HP-Compaq-dc5800-Small-Form-Factor:/usr/local$ mkdir pgsql
mkdir: cannot create directory `pgsql': Permission denied
```

But I am getting error:

```
Permission denied
```

How can I resolve and create directory `pgsql` in this location `/usr/local$`

Kindly suggest me, hope for reply.

Thanks

Comment: Some more useful links that may help you..! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450129/mkdir-permission-denied http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246114/php-mkdir-permission-denied-problem

Comment: This question would probably be better suited for http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You have to check your user name to have permission for creating directory in the folder `/usr/local$`

Check your permission for the folder by the command

```
ls -ltr /usr
```

[Link](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php) to refer about file permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a `Permission denied` error because you do not have access rights to create a directory in `/usr/local`. You can determine the access rights for these directories by using the `stat` command. The output will look something like this.

```
$> stat -c '%n %A %G %U' /usr /usr/local
/usr drwxr-xr-x root root
 /usr/local drwxr-xr-x root root
```

Now double check who you are. You can use the `whoami` command or the `id` command invoked below twice to reveal both username and group.

```
$> id -un; id -gn
```

In the `stat` output, `root:root` owns both `/usr` and `/usr/local` and only the owner may create (write) new directories based on the access rights. In order to create the directories, I'd recommend either becoming `root` or trying the command with `sudo`. If this is not possible, I'm afraid you'll have to create the directory elsewhere or contact the administrator of that machine.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to be root to do such things in /usr/local.